# Select distinct values in each 150 columns of a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Need to build a query , I havea table with 2 billion rows and 150 columns.

Need to find out distinct values in each of 150 distinct columns and maybe store that in a table?

Comment: Assuming a table with 2 columns and the following data, what is the expected result? (1,1),(1,2),(2,3)

Comment: In column 1 (1,2 ) and in column 2 ( 1,2,3)

Comment: Edited question a bit

Comment: why cant you select distinct on the concatenated columns?

Comment: No, i need distinct values in each of the 150.columns and not unique across combined columns.

Comment: why you don't you post a small example? create table statement, insert statement, and expected results. something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d183f/2

Comment: I am new here.. but I will try to post example.

Comment: Suppose table1 has say 5 columns col1 vales ( 1,2,3,1,4) col2 ( 1,2,6,1) col3 has vales as ( 3, 2 ,4 ) col4 has vales as (1,2,3) and col5 has vales as ( 6,9,1,6,9,7,8,3) total rows in table are 8. If column does not have 8 rows which means there will be null vales.   Expected result will be

Comment: Col 1 - distinct vales are 1,2,3,4 col2 - 1,2,6 col3 - 3,2,4 col4 1,2,3 and col5 6,9,1,7,8,3.

Comment: Well, what would the resulting rows look like?

Comment: Result.should come as a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view target layout is wrong. Yes, you *could* do it - display 150 columns one next to another, each of them having distinct values only. But, that's difficult to maintain and you'd have to write quite a lot of code.

Therefore, another suggestion which fits A5 paper size (or less, if you use smaller font :)). "My" target table contains only two columns, pairs of column name itself and its distinct values. To accomplish that, let Oracle do the *difficult* part of it by writing query for you. How? By dynamic SQL.

My example is based on Scott's `EMP` table. I'm displaying command that is being run so that you'd see what is actually being executed; you don't have to do that. Also, my `value` column's datatype is `varchar2` which means that I'm relying on Oracle's capabilities to implicitly convert different datatypes to it. Works on my simple test case. If it doesn't in your, bad luck - you'll have to put some more effort into it.

OK, enough talking, let's start working.

Target table:

```
SQL> create table target
  2    (column_name varchar2(30),
  3     value       varchar2(50)
  4    );

Table created.
```

Sample data (represents your *150-columns-table*):

```
SQL> select * from emp order by deptno;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.1981       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.1982       1300                    10
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.1981       2975                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.1981       3000                    20
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.1983       1100                    20
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.1980        800                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.1982       3000                    20
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.1981       1250        500         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.1981       1500          0         30
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.1981       1600        300         30
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.1981        950                    30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.1981       2850                    30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.1981       1250       1400         30

14 rows selected.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select column_name
  5                  from user_tab_columns
  6                  where table_name = 'EMP'
  7                  order by column_id
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      l_str := 'insert into target (column_name, value) ' ||
 11               'select distinct ' || chr(39) || cur_r.column_name || chr(39) ||
 12                              ', '|| cur_r.column_name || ' from emp';
 13      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 14      execute immediate l_str;
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'EMPNO', EMPNO from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'ENAME', ENAME from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'JOB', JOB from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'MGR', MGR from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'HIREDATE', HIREDATE from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'SAL', SAL from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'COMM', COMM from emp
insert into target (column_name, value) select distinct 'DEPTNO', DEPTNO from emp

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From target order by column_name, value;

COLUMN_NAME                    VALUE
------------------------------ -----------------------------
COMM                           0
COMM                           1400
COMM                           300
COMM                           500
COMM
DEPTNO                         10          --> true; there are only 3 different
DEPTNO                         20          --  departments: 
DEPTNO                         30          --  10, 20 and 30
<snip>
JOB                            ANALYST     --> the same goes for jobs - this is
JOB                            CLERK       --  a list of distinct jobs
JOB                            MANAGER     --  in the EMP table
JOB                            PRESIDENT
JOB                            SALESMAN
<snip>
```

So, if you want to know distinct values in any of those columns, you'd simply

```
SQL> select value
  2  from target
  3  where column_name = 'JOB';

VALUE
-------------------------------------
ANALYST
PRESIDENT
CLERK
SALESMAN
MANAGER

SQL>
```

As simple as that.